# cascading dropdownlistfor not working upon submitting the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have create a Cascading DropDownList for country and city. It work fine when it retrieves the data but when I try to submit the form the City dropdownlist gets empty without posting the data.. here is my code... (I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730953/Cascading-Dropdown-List-With-MVC-LINQ-to-SQL-and-A) link)

Could anyone tell what's wrong here
Here is what i have done...

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetAllCitiesByCountryId(string countryId)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(countryId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("countryId");
        }
        int id = 0;
        bool isValid = Int32.TryParse(countryId, out id);
        var cities = _CountryRepository.GetAllCitiesByCountryId(id);
        var result = (from s in cities
                      select new
                      {
                          id = s.ID,
                          name = s.DESCRIPTION
                      }).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View

```
$(function () {
        $("#CountryID").change(function () {
            var selectedItem = $(this).val();
            var cities = $("#CityID");
            var citiesProgress = $("#cities-loading-progress");
            citiesProgress.show();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetAllCitiesByCountryId"))",
                data: { "countryId": selectedItem },
                success: function (data) {
                    cities.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                    cities.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name));
                    });
                citiesProgress.hide();
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve cities.');
                citiesProgress.hide();
            }
            });
            //$('#CityID').change(function() {
            //    this.form.submit();
    });
    });

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CityID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityID, Model.City, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            <span id="cities-loading-progress" style="display: none;">Please wait..</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CityID, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your code looks good, do you get CityID null? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: i debug it. i don't get CityID null. it gets what i have given to at at the time of submitting the form

Comment: so it is working fine?

Comment: but when i submit the form the country dropdownlist remains selected but the city dropdownlist gets empty and remains on the same view page. that's the problem its not posting anything

Comment: Its unclear what your actual problem is. From your last comment you seem to be suggesting that when you submit, the 2nd dropdownlist is empty when you return the view (which it will be unless you have reassigned the `SelectList`)

Comment: i mean to say is that when i click the submit button second dropdownlist becomes empty and it does not save any data back to the database. i want to save country and city back to database which i have selected from dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in `RouteConfig.cs` file:

```
routes.MapRoute("GetAllCitiesByCountryId",
                "ControllerName/GetAllCitiesByCountryId/",
                new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "GetAllCitiesByCountryId" },
                new[] { "CountryCityApplication.Controllers" });
```

It's because you use this:

```
url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetAllCitiesByCountryId"))",
```